# Custom resolver failing on a specific environment

Tags: custom-resolver

We have a custom resolver that adds all Keyword metadata linked Components when a Category is published.  We've compiled our resolver and altered the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` to utilise:

```
<add itemType="Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Category">
    <resolvers>
        <add type="CustomerResolvers.CategoryResolver" assembly="CustomerResolvers" />
    </resolvers>
</add>
```

This correctly returns the Category, and all linked DCPs, but only locally, or on our test server. Our dev server only returns the Category. On dev, it seems to be doing something, as logging shows that it finds the linked Components. They just aren't listed when you click **Show items to publish**.

Both dev/test have the same content, and the same version of Tridion. I didn't set up the servers, so I'm wondering if anyone has any idea as to why the different behaviour? I'm not ruling out stupidity, but have run out of ideas.

Comment: Can you confirm the same version of the DLL (`CustomerResolvers`) is available and configured on both environments (including on all Publishers and possible outscaled CME servers)?

Comment: Yes, same version. Each server has publisher service running locally.

Comment: Which version of Tridion? I think the "show items to publish" thing only triggers custom resolvers as of 2013 (or maybe there was a defect in some version where this didn't work)

Comment: Update Version: Hotfix Rollup SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 - 1

Comment: In that version the `Show items to publish` does indeed trigger the execution of custom resolvers.

Comment: Are the same DCPs published in both environments (i.e. the environment(s) you're resolving to)?

Comment: Thanks for the idea Mark. The component template wasn't configured correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I said not to rule out stupidity. On the dev server, the component template was not configured for a dynamic component presentation. The custom resolver would not have included the required DCPs.

In my defence the nature of the remote server access means I have to set this up manually. I guess I could keep generating Content Porter packages, but that's another world of pain.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. Might I suggest that you accept your own answer so this question "becomes closed"?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try attaching to the process and debugging it? Do note that if the deployed dll is different than the code you've put the breakpoint in, the breakpoint won't be hit. Also, for this you need to deploy a `debug` build of the resolver.